# Keyword Searches

Tags: excel, text, full-text-search

I have a project where I am given a large amount of information and a description of what issues I am handling. I would like to create a cell at the end of the row that would return yes or no after it performs a search across a row for a specific keyword or piece of text. I have tried using the if(Search()) function, but it only allows for one cell in the row to be searched for the keyword. This would work, but the Keyword(s) that I'm searching for may appear in different columns of the row. Is there anyway that I can create a formula to search the entire row for specific texts? And if any instance of a list of keywords that I have put into the formula appear, can it result in a customizable text response (Yes or no)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Say in the first row we want to know if we can find "happiness" anywhere in A1 thru C1.  In D1 enter:

**=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("Happiness",A1 & B1 & C1)),"No","Yes")**

If you have more cells, just increase the concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `COUNTIF` to locate a piece of text -any result greater than **0** means the text has been found

use `=COUNTIF(A1:F4,"Your Text")` if you have to have a full cell match

use `=COUNTIF(A1:F4,"*Your Text*")` if you want a partial match (e.g. "Dog" will match "CatDog" and "Dogma")

Wrap this in an `IF` statement to get your desired response

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:F4,"*" & G1 & "*")>0,"Yes","No")
```